# Rename Woocommerce "Orders" admin submenu

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, backend, gettext

How can I rename the order submenu in WooCommerce?

[image]

I've tried it this way but it's not working:

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'rename_texts', 20, 3 );
function rename_texts( $translated ) {      
    switch ( $translated ) {
        case 'Bestellungen' :
            $translated = __( 'My Tests', 'woocommerce' );
            break;
    }

    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: I know, silence is golden but not here. It would be very helpful if you can help me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `gettext_with_context` hook instead of `gettext` to be able to make it work this way:

```
add_filter('gettext_with_context', 'rename_woocommerce_admin_text', 100, 4 );
function rename_woocommerce_admin_text( $translated, $text, $context, $domain ) {
    if( $domain == 'woocommerce' && $context == 'Admin menu name' && $translated == 'Bestellungen' ) {
        // Here your custom text
        $translated = 'Custom text';
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

Or you can also use this that will target the non translated "Orders" text instead:

```
add_filter('gettext_with_context', 'rename_woocommerce_admin_text', 100, 4 );
function rename_woocommerce_admin_text( $translated, $text, $context, $domain ) {
    if( $domain == 'woocommerce' && $context == 'Admin menu name' && $text == 'Orders' ) {
        $translated = __('Custom text', $domain );
    }
    return $translated;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Is it possible to rename all texts which hast "Orders" in it with your function? Should I change my question or ask a new one?

Comment: @Mr.Jo This answer code only work for "Orders" submenu item, so you should better ask a new question with all the necessary details. Just remember that you can't ask multiple questions in one or a question that involve too many different cases.